# How do optimise the performance of Remmina?

Tags: 11.10, rdp, remmina

I have installed Remmina on my Oneiric Ubuntu laptop for home RDP access to my work Windows 7 PC.

This works, I can access my work PC etc...however the performance is not what I had hoped.
I am using the default settings for Remmina, and after researching through Google I have set my mouse pointers option on tehe windows 7 box to none.

Can any one else offer any advise on how to configure Remmina prefernces to optimise the performance please?
Thank you

Answer (score 7):

AFAIK Remmina uses FreeRDP as its RDP backend. Since FreeRDP is under heavy development the FreeRDP version (0.8.2-2build1) in 11.10 may not be as optimized as the development versions from the FreeRDP homepage.

For high-performance (kind of) RDP connections to Windows 7 (or other RDP servers) I use **rdesktop** (command line) with the following settings:

```
rdesktop -a 16 -z -x m -P SERVERNAME
```